# How to group values in list of lists and convert to list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, type-conversion, grouping

I have a list of lists with row and column numbers, as follows:

```
list_of_lists = [[100, 300],
                 [100, 301],
                 [100, 302],
                 [101, 200],
                 [101, 201],
                 [102, 210]]
```

Where the row number is the first value of each sub-list; the column number the second value.

I need to convert this somehow to a list of dictionaries, as follows:

```
dict = [{'row': 100, 'columns': [300, 301, 302]},
        {'row': 101, 'columns': [200, 201]},
        {'row': 102, 'columns': 210}]
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Do it inefficiently then improve it.

Comment: what have you tried so far? A tip: you probably want all the values to have the same structure, so in the last item a list with a single value instead of just the value not in a list

Comment: I tried defaultdict as @Datanovice suggested and it worked. I also used numpy.unique to get unique column values only. Like this: [{'row': k, 'column': np.unique(v)} for k,v in value_dict.items()]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `defaultdict` from the collections library.

first we group your items then create your nested list of dictionaries with a list comp.

```
from collections import defaultdict

group_dict = defaultdict(list)
for item in list_of_lists:
    group_dict[item[0]].append(item[1])

final = [{'row' : k, 'column' : v} for k,v in group_dict.items()]
```

---

```
print(final)
[{'row': 100, 'column': [300, 301, 302]},
 {'row': 101, 'column': [200, 201]},
 {'row': 102, 'column': [210]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a real quick way to do it, but it aint pretty. Here are two ways to output the data (the first one isn't your preferred output but it may make your data easier to access in the future):

```py
list_of_lists = [[100, 300],
                 [100, 301],
                 [100, 302],
                 [101, 200],
                 [101, 201],
                 [102, 210]]

# create a dict with empty lists as keys
pivot = {i[0]: [] for i in list_of_lists}
for i in list_of_lists:
    # append the value of the first item key to the second item
    pivot[i[0]].append(i[1])

# split dict items into their own dicts with row and column keys
pivot_with_keys = [{'row': k, 'columns': v}
                   for k, v in pivot.items()]

print(f'rows as keys: {pivot}')
print(f'text as keys: {pivot_with_keys}')
```

Output

```py
rows as keys: {100: [300, 301, 302], 101: [200, 201], 102: [210]}
text as keys: [{'row': 100, 'columns': [300, 301, 302]}, {'row': 101, 'columns': [200, 201]}, {'row': 102, 'columns': [210]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

an alternative is to use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), [islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and [chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) from itertools : group the values based on the first entry in each list, get the groups and append into a dictionary via a for loop:

```
from itertools import groupby, islice, chain
from operator import itemgetter    

#note that for groupby, the data has to be sorted
#easily achieved using the sorted method
#supplied data is already sorted, so i'll skip

m = groupby(list_of_lists, key = itemgetter(0))
d = []
for k,v in m: 
    #zip the groupings and keep only the [-1] entry for each
    res = islice(zip(*v),1,None)
    #merge into one
    res = list(chain.from_iterable(res))
    d.append({'row':k, 'columns':res})

print(d)

[{'row': 100, 'columns': [300, 301, 302]},
 {'row': 101, 'columns': [200, 201]},
 {'row': 102, 'columns': [210]}]
```

note: it is an alternative - defaultdict method is faster (about 2X)